# How can I run maps application with startActivityForResult to let the user choose a location then i get it back to my application

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity

I want to run Google maps application on android phone from my application using startActivityForResult. Then I want the user to select a point and when he/she press OK (on Google maps app) Google maps app return this point coordinates to me.

Is there a way,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can still open Google Map with in your application